# Is there a way to pass a reference to ngrx store to a (plugin) component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript, ngrx, frp

Maybe I'm doing this wrong. What I want to do is have my action payload pass a reference to the app store and an instance of an action to dispatch when the component is done with an async operation.

My other option was to pass in an observable, subscribe to it... but, nonetheless, when I try to do this:

```
this.store.dispatch(new actions.SnackbarActionShow({
    message: 'Would you like to know the answer!',
    actionTitle: 'Yes',
    answerMessage: 'Well too bad, I\'m not telling.',
    store: this.store, // this causes error
    actionToEmit: new actions.SnackbarActionClicked(),
});
```

I get the error `Attempted to assign to readonly property.` while everything else works. I can assign the actionToEmit, etc. So, I'm thinking, we can't really pass the store by reference, only inject it... but I can't since this is a {N} plugin running out of node_modules. The end goal is to have the component dispatch the action from the store...

Any good way to do this?

Edit:

tried doing a callback, but it's weird. Just passing in a callback causes an error when evoked that `action.payload` is undefined, even though that variable is not in the scope of the callback function. BUT ONLY if I try to dispatch a new action in the callback. I can log just fine.

```
@Effect() public snackbarActionShow$ = this.actions$
.ofType(aa.SnackbarActionTypes.ACTION_SHOW)
.map((action) => {
  const callback = () => {
      this.log.debug('called back');
      this.store.dispatch( new aa.SnackbarActionClicked() );
  };
  this.snackbar.showAction(action.payload, callback);
  return new aa.SnackbarNoOp();
});
```

Comment: I don't know of a way to pass a reference of the store.  Is it possible to use a smart component/dumb component setup where the parent component handles the communication with the store?

Comment: Well, this is from an Effect, not a component at all. Basically, instead of components listening to the store, the Effect handles Actions and creates "side effects" in the component. I think maybe having the Effect pass in a callback which then dispatches the new Action may be the way to go.

Comment: yeah, it's weird. just passing in a callback causes an error when evoked that action.payload is undefined, even though that variable is not in the scope of the callback function.